# Not able to compile C++ using cygwin

Tags: c++, cygwin

New to C++ so I'm confused.

Trying to compile a very simple hello world using netbeans and cygwin, and I get this error.

Edit: Also tried from cygwin and got the same error.

```
  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -ladvapi32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lshell32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -luser32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lkernel32
```

What am I missing? I did a complete install of cygwin.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you try compiling from the Cygwin shell ?

```
cat >hello.c <<EOF
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
        printf("Hello World !!!\n");
}
EOF
gcc -v hello.c
```

If it works, it's probably a problem with your Netbeans configuration.
Especially, you could compare it to the LIBRARY_PATH you have in the gcc logs from the console.

Comment: I get the same error. `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -ladvapi32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lshell32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -luser32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lkernel32
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 1):

I had to install **w32api-runtime** (which pulled w32api-headers too) to make cygwin**64** proceed with ./configure.

Prior to that, I had to *manually install* **mpfr** and **mpc** - gcc-core-5.2.1 d*oesn't have these as dependencies* somehow, despite it seems to be linked with them, and as a result it refuses to work, crying about missing **cygmpfr-4.dll** and **cygmpc-3.dll**. This clearly seems like maintainer/packager lack of care - this latter problem is known for at least four years now...